# CoreData to Array in Swift

Tags: objective-c, arrays, core-data, swift

I am trying to fetch data from CoreData and return it as an array for charting in a popular charting library.  The code below runs fine and I can print the data to the console, however I want to fill self.hkdataBase with the entries within CoreData and Return it.  Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var hkdataBase = [HKdataBase]()
```

....

```
func fetchCoreData () -> NSArray {

//Setting up Core Data
    var context = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate).managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "HKdataBase")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

//Fetching Data
    self.hkdataBase = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)! as [HKdataBase]
    if hkdataBase.count > 0 {
        for i in hkdataBase {

        **I WANT TO FILL self.hkdataBase WITH i ELEMENTS HERE **  ->  println(i.hr_data) WORKS FINE


        }
    } else {
        println("No results")
    }
}
**return self.hkdataBase with elements**
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**
I want to Return an Array from the fetched data in CoreData.  The hr_data are Heart Rate measures and hr_date are the associated NSDate.  The HKdataBase looks like this:

import Foundation
import CoreData

class HKdataBase: NSManagedObject {

```
@NSManaged var hr_date: NSDate
@NSManaged var hr_data: NSNumber
```

}

Comment: hr_data in your model is a number, not an array. Why would you expect an array? Please explain what you're trying to accomplish with your data model. I would guess what you actually want is a second entity that has a to-many relationship with the main entity. The entities in a core data database are like tables / objects. e.g. You might have an entity called Person that has a name, age, and height. Each person might be associated with 0 or more other objects, e.g. a Book

Comment: Yes, that is my problem, how do I make it an array?  Ok so my CoreData model is wrong?  I am trying to return an array so that I can use the array to graph the numbers

Comment: Can't help you if you don't explain what you're trying to accomplish. (Add this detail by editing your question, not by commenting)

Comment: The result of `context.executeFetchRequest(...)! as [HKdataBase]` is already an array. What else do you need?

Comment: if I return self.hkdataBase I just get an empty array [, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ].  How do I fill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the fetch, you already have your managed objects in `self.hkdataBase`. Managed objects are KVC compliant, so to get just one kind of value out if it is quite simple.

```
var hrData = (self.hkdataBase as NSArray).valueForKey("hr_data") as NSArray
```

You now have an array containing your hr_data, presumably an array of `NSNumber` objects.

Comment: Thank you so, so much Mundi !  I have been trying to get this to work for 3 whole days now and left work (startup) today quite demoralized(live in Europe) .  You brought me one step closer to our goal - THANK YOU !